# How to call function without ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

How we can call function in angularjs without ng-click. I tried ng-show but my function is running again and again.  Can any one help me.
Basically i want to file function without ng-click.

```
    <button ng-show="Temp" ng-click="TemplateE5()"> </button>
```

i donot want ng-click. it should fire automatically

```
<angucomplete-alt id="Te1" placeholder="Please type name of template "
    pause="100"  maxlength="20"  input-changed="test"
    selected-object="Temp" local-data="myTemplate"
    search-fields="NAME" title-field="NAME" minlength="0"
    input-class="form-control form-control-small"
    match-class="highlight">
</angucomplete-alt>

<button ng-show="Temp" ng-click="TemplateE5()"> </button>
```

controller Side

```
    $scope.TemplateE5 = function () {
    $scope.users.Time = $scope.Temp.time;
    $scope.users.Paper= $scope.Temp.paper;}
```

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: On which condition do you want the function to run? Do you want to run it after a specific time interval or on a particular action by the user?

Comment: if you want to run functions called when controller init just call then with ng-init ="yourFunction()"

Comment: i also tried ng-init. Not working

Comment: `<angucomplete-alt id="Te1" ng-init="TemplateE5()"` ....... the other attributes.

Comment: Sorry dear. It's still not working. I want to fire my function after select selecting temp

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried ng-click instead of ng-init inside autocomplete-alt

Answer (score 1):

You can run it from your controller if you know the ID:

```
$scope.getSessionsForSpeaker(id);
```

You can use ng-init to run it when that element loads:

```
<a ng-init="getSessionsForSpeaker(speaker.id)"></a>
```

You can also use ng-mouseover if you want to run it when the mouse is over that element

```
<a ng-mouseover="getSessionsForSpeaker(speaker.id)"></a>
```

> All depends when you want to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you every one. I used ng-click inside angucomplete-alt it works

```
<angucomplete-alt id="Te1" ng-click="TemplateE5()"
                  placeholder="Please type name of template "
                  pause="100"  maxlength="20"  input-changed="test"
                  selected-object="Temp" local-data="myTemplate"
                  search-fields="NAME" title-field="NAME" 
                  minlength="0"
                  input-class="form-control form-control-small"
                  match-class="highlight">
</angucomplete-alt>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`app.directive('ngEnter', function () {
return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
        if(event.which === 13) {
            scope.$apply(function (){
                scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
            });

            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
};
```

});`

On the web page

```
<input ng-enter="myFunc()" ng-model="..." />
```